# My program will not print anything when run, after entering a few random numbers it'll work (with many bugs)

Tags: c++, object

I am working on a assignment for my programming class. I am perplexed as to what is happening. My code compiles without issue, but when I run it, it does not do anything. I decided to hit enter a few times, still nothing. Then I put in "1" and hit enter, and after four times, the menu that should have displayed when the program is run was finally displayed. Can anyone help me spot the bug?

Header:

```
/* 
+-----------------------------------+
|               Fruit               |
+-----------------------------------+
| -fruitName : String               |
| -priceOfFruit : Double            |
| -numberOfFruit : Integer          |
| -numberSold : Integer             |
+-----------------------------------+
| <<constructor>>                   |
|   Fruit(name: String              |
|         price: Double             |
|         num : Integer)            |
| <<constructor>>                   |
|   Fruit(name: String)             | 
| <<constructor>>                   | 
|   Fruit()                         |
| +setFruitName(name : String)      |
| +setPriceOfFruit(price : Double)  |
| +setNumberOfFruit(num : Integer)  |         
| +setNumberSold(num : Integer)     |
| +getFruitName() : String          | 
| +getPriceOfFruit() : Double       |
| +getNumberOfFruit() : Integer     |
| +getNumberSold() : Integer        |
| +amountSold() : Double            |
| +buy() : Boolean                  |
+-----------------------------------+
*/

#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef FRUIT_H
#define FRUIT_H

class Fruit
{
private:

   string fruitName;
   double priceOfFruit;
   int numberOfFruit;
   int numberSold;

public:
   Fruit(string name, double price, int num);
   Fruit(string name);
   Fruit();
   void setFruitName(string name);
   void setPriceOfFruit(double price);
   void setNumberOfFruit(int num);
   void setNumberSold(int num);
   string getFruitName();
   double getPriceOfFruit();
   int getNumberOfFruit();
   int getNumberSold();
   double amountSold();
   bool buy();
};

#endif
```

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Fruit.h"

using namespace std;

Fruit::Fruit(string name, double price, int num)
{
    fruitName = name;
    priceOfFruit = price;
    numberOfFruit = num;
    numberSold = 0;
}

Fruit::Fruit(string name)
{
    fruitName = name;
    priceOfFruit = 0;
    numberOfFruit = 0;
    numberSold = 0;
}

Fruit::Fruit()
{
    fruitName = "";
    priceOfFruit = 0;
    numberOfFruit = 0;
    numberSold = 0;
}

void Fruit::setFruitName(string name)
{
    fruitName = name;
}

void Fruit::setPriceOfFruit(double price)
{
    if (price >= 0)
        priceOfFruit = price;
    else
        while (price < 0)
            cout << "\nThe price cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
            cin >> price;
                if (price >= 0)
                    priceOfFruit = price;

}

void Fruit::setNumberOfFruit(int num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        numberOfFruit = num;
    else
        while (num < 0)
            cout << "\nThe number of fruit cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
            cin >> num;
                if (num >= 0)
                    numberOfFruit = num;
}

string Fruit::getFruitName()
{
    return fruitName;
}

double Fruit::getPriceOfFruit()
{
    return priceOfFruit;
}

int Fruit::getNumberOfFruit()
{
    return numberOfFruit;
}

int Fruit::getNumberSold()
{
    return numberSold;
}

double Fruit::amountSold()
{
    return numberSold * priceOfFruit;
}

bool Fruit::buy()
{
    bool transaction;
    int buying, available = 0;

    numberOfFruit = available;

    cout << "\n" << fruitName << " .......... " << "$" 
         << setfill('0') << setw(4) << priceOfFruit
         << "\nPlease enter the number of "<< fruitName 
         << "s to purchase: " << endl;
    cin >> buying;

    if (buying > available) {
        transaction = false;
        return transaction;
    } 
    else {
        numberOfFruit = available - buying;
        numberSold = buying;
        transaction = true;
        return transaction;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Fruit.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int selection = 5;
    bool transaction;
    double total;
    Fruit apple("Apple", 1.99, 10);
    Fruit banana("Banana");
    Fruit orange;

    banana.setPriceOfFruit(0.79);
    banana.setNumberOfFruit(8);

    orange.setFruitName("Orange");
    orange.setPriceOfFruit(1.49);
    orange.setNumberOfFruit(7);

    do {

        cout << "  Fruit Stand  "
             << "\n---------------"
             << "\n1. Buy Apple"
             << "\n2. Buy Banana"
             << "\n3. Buy Orange"
             << "\n4. Print Total"
             << "\n0. Quit" 
             << "\nPlease make a selection: " << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        while (selection < 0 && selection > 4) {
            cout << "\nSorry, that was an invalid selection."
                 << "Please try again: " << endl;
            cin >> selection;
        }

        if (selection == 1)
            transaction = apple.buy();
        else if (selection == 2)
            transaction = banana.buy();
        else if (selection == 3)
            transaction = orange.buy();
        else if (selection == 4)
            cout << "Your current total is $" << setfill('0') << setw(4) << total << endl;
        else
            cout << "\nThank you for shopping at the Fruit Stand!" << endl;

        if (transaction == true) {
            cout << "\nThank you for your purchase!\n" << endl;
            total = apple.amountSold() + banana.amountSold() + orange.amountSold();
        }
        else
            cout << "\nSorry, out of stock.\n" << endl;

    } while (selection != 0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds normal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doing what you expect:

```
void Fruit::setNumberOfFruit(int num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        numberOfFruit = num;
    else
        while (num < 0)
            cout << "\nThe number of fruit cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
            cin >> num;
                if (num >= 0)
                    numberOfFruit = num;
}
```

Please use braces - this is C++, not python. As it is right now, the code is equivalent to:

```
void Fruit::setNumberOfFruit(int num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        numberOfFruit = num;
    else
        while (num < 0)
            cout << "\nThe number of fruit cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    if (num >= 0)
        numberOfFruit = num;
}
```

Which means that when you call `setNumberOfFruit()` in `main()`, it will *always* try to read a number from `stdin`. Change that to:

```
void Fruit::setNumberOfFruit(int num)
{
    if (num >= 0)
        numberOfFruit = num;
    else {
        while (num < 0) {
            cout << "\nThe number of fruit cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
            cin >> num;
                if (num >= 0)
                    numberOfFruit = num;
        }
    }
}
```

And in fact, maybe a better choice would be to do this instead:

```
void Fruit::setNumberOfFruit(int num)
{
    while (num < 0) {
        cout << "\nThe number of fruit cannot be negative. Please try again: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }
    numberOfFruit = num;
}
```

Or, even better, throw an exception if `num` is not in the range you expect, and handle that exception in `main()` or wherever the setter is called - in my opinion, it is not very good design to do the sort of stuff you're doing inside a setter method.

Comment: Thank you! I admit, I'd been learning Python before this, I must have reverted back to my habits of not including braces while I was working on the implementation file.

Comment: Regarding the inclusion of handling input validation in a setter method, we had clear instructions to do so. We seem to break a lot of programming conventions in the classroom or are otherwise taught conventions that aren't really conventions. I'm always hearing what I should be doing versus what I was told to do by a professor when I post here for help.

Comment: @AxelFinkel Well, the assignment probably has other things in mind, so you should just follow your professor's instructions. You will eventually learn why this would be bad design though (I hope).